# How to sqlite statement to update duedate of the row whose name is myname and dob is mydob

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I have the below statement to update a row in the table

```
    ContentValues myValues = new ContentValues();
    myValues.put("duedate", duedate);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, myValues,"name" + "=?" + "dob" + "=?", new String[] { myname,mydob });
```

I want to update the duedate of the row whose name is myname and dob is mydob.

The above code is not working. Can you please help me how to do it.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

`mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, myValues,"name = myname and dob = mydob", null);`

Comment: return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, myValues, "name='"+myname+"' AND dob='"+mydob+"'", null);